# Cargo package doesn't work with Rust's workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I create a "workspace" with several folder within it following [the tutorial I read here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html)

It runs successfully with `cargo run` or `cargo build`

if all of the package were independent from each other, `cargo package` would run successfully. But as soon as one package depends on the other the `cargo package` will fail.

It displays: `no matching package named "foo_2" found. location searched: registry "crates-io"`. Which is pretty weird, since I specifically add a local path on the dependencies.

Is this an intended behavior? if so, then why should I bother with workspace at all ?

The root Cargo.toml

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "foo_1",
    "foo_2",
]
```

foo_1/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foo_1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# error here. It can't found the foo_2 package.
[dependencies] 
foo_2 = { path = "../foo_2", version = "0.1.0" }
```

foo_2/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foo_2"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
```

[image]

Error message:

```
PS E:\Works\Experimentals\rust-workspace> cargo package --workspace
warning: manifest has no description, license, license-file, documentation, homepage or repository.
See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#package-metadata for more info.
   Packaging foo_1 v0.1.0 (E:\Works\Experimentals\rust-workspace\foo_1)
   Verifying foo_1 v0.1.0 (E:\Works\Experimentals\rust-workspace\foo_1)
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to verify package tarball

Caused by:
  no matching package named `foo_2` found
  location searched: registry `crates-io`
  required by package `foo_1 v0.1.0 (E:\Works\Experimentals\rust-workspace\target\package\foo_1-0.1.0)`
```

Comment: this is weird, are you sure you have no typo or somthing like that?

Comment: @Netwave : I'm sure that this is not a typo. I create a new fresh project just to confirm this. Just create a workspace with two package "foo_1" and "foo_2". the `cargo package` successfully runs IF both packages were independent. As soon as you put a `foo_2` into dependencies of `foo_1`, you will receive the same error message as I do

Comment: Can you share the content of foo_2/Cargo.toml

Comment: @AhmedMasud: it's there. It has no dependencies whatsoever.

Comment: foo_2 can only be a dependency if it's a lib. :P you are missing the [lib] declaration in the Cargo.toml

Comment: @AhmedMasud: `foo_2` is a library. I will upload the workspace structure

Comment: The answer given by @Enet is closest to the correct one, you do need to publish the crate to manage it via workspaces, seems to be a limitation on behalf of workspaces + packages integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packaging and publishing crates *requires all dependencies* of said crate to also be available in a registry. For publishing this is relatively obvious, since consumers also need to be able to fetch and build transitive dependencies. Creating tarballs also happens to have the same constraints at the moment, so it is not possible if they are not meant to be published.

Whenever you have a project with many crates in a single workspace and wish to publish them on crates.io, you would start with the crate without dependencies and work your way up to the other crates.

```sh
cargo publish -p foo_2
cargo publish -p foo_1
```

Or, using [`cargo-workspaces`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-workspaces):

```sh
cargo workspaces publish
```

> Is this an intended behavior?

One can still publish crates in a workspace, so long as this is done in the right order. For packaging, it is a limitation at the time of writing. The current behavior could be linked with packaging being primarily part of publishing, so this could *probably* be improved.

> If so, then why should I bother with workspace at all?

Tangential to the matter here. Workspaces exist mainly to settle other concerns, such as having a single source of compiled dependencies with a shared dependency lock. This distinction is [described in that same link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).

Comment: So basically I need to `package` each project, one by one just like `cargo publish` ? If it was the case, then what should I do if I wish not to publish it ? or if it was a private project?

Comment: And also how do I `cargo package` the `foo_1` (which depends on `foo_2` project) ? Do I need to bring the binary `foo_2` package  into `foo_1` ?

Comment: Answer clarified. It is currently not possible with Cargo alone. It may be unusual to depend on crate tarballs like this.

Comment: so workspace only works with published project ? I had to publish both `foo_1` and `foo_2`  to crates.io to make it work ?

Comment: This is my opinion, but shouldn't the workspace's purpose is to split a large project into smaller pieces ? This defeats that purpose if I need to compile each project / piece and also had to publish it to crates.io

Comment: @DennyHiu Workspaces _do_ work in general, as described at the end of the answer. It's just that, at the moment, they just do not support the `cargo package` command if one of the crates isn't published. If you feel strongly about this, you could consider filing an issue at [rust-lang/cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo) presenting your case for why this should be supported.

Comment: well.... then I should avoid workspace and think of other ways to restructure a large project with Rust. Thank you